# Polymer blocking keyboard input?

Tags: polymer, adobe-extension

I inherited an Adobe CEP extension at work. Trying to wrap my head around an issue that makes it so absolutely no input from keyboard works on text inputs. To elaborate, absolutely no keyboard input works in Polymer's text inputs. The input get's focused, but if I type anything in them I get the mac error alert sound. The only key that I was able to make work was "tab". Anything else does not work. It's built using Polymer. At first I was unsure what's causing the issue, and since I inherited this project I was confused where to start. After about a day of debugging, I believe it's related to Polymer somehow. The reason for this is, if I remove the Polymer HTML element that renders it, and just put an input there, the input works. It only seems to block input inside the `<template> ... </template>`. I've looked all over the internet for any clues on what could be causing Polymer to block this input, there's no errors in console or anything, and I've come up short handed.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: what is the code of you "polymer-input"? are there maybe some validators attached to it?

Comment: No it doesnt matter if i do polymer-input (paper-input), or even just a regular input. Any input at all that lives in the polymer code does not let you type anything and the error sound occurs.

Comment: that certainly sounds strange - but hard to tell what could cause it (without actually looking at the code itself) - usually, that definitely works

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. Actually, it is not related to polymer, but to the webcomponents polyfill. If you try the following source code inside an Adobe CEP extension, you will see that you can click inside both the  elements, select any text, but you are not able to edit it.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        // Force all polyfills on
        if (window.customElements) window.customElements.forcePolyfill = true;
        ShadyDOM = {
            force: true
        };
        ShadyCSS = {
            shimcssproperties: true
        };
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <template id="x-foo-from-template">
        <input value="from template">
    </template>
    <script>
        let tmpl = document.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');

        customElements.define('x-foo-from-template', class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
                    mode: 'open'
                });
                shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
            }
        });

        customElements.define('x-foo-from-dynamic', class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
                    mode: 'open'
                });
                var inputEl = document.createElement('input');
                inputEl.value = "from created element";
                shadowRoot.appendChild(inputEl);
            }
        });
    </script>

    <x-foo-from-template></x-foo-from-template>
    <x-foo-from-dynamic></x-foo-from-dynamic>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have created an issue on github https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/1006

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue, we finally found documented that Adobe will hand over all keypresses to the host application unless it can determine that an input or dropdown element has focus. I expect this is done using a simple check on `document.activeElement`. When the Shadow DOM is involved, Adobe would have to do something like

```
let target = document.activeElement;
while (target.shadowRoot && target.shadowRoot.activeElement) {
  target = target.shadowRoot.activeElement;
}
```

in order to find the underlying `<input>` element.

Since this is currently not working, we needed to use `registerKeyEventsInterest` to explicitly have all keypresses be processed by our code.

```
var csInterface = new CSInterface();
var keyEvents = [];
// All the keyCodes you need, with the modifiers used
keyEvents.push({ keyCode: 0 });
keyEvents.push({ keyCode: 0, metaKey: true });
// ...
csInterface.registerKeyEventsInterest(JSON.stringify(keyEvents));
```

We actually went ahead and looped 0..255 and registered for all modifiers. With the exception of keyboard based copy-paste, we now have full functionality with our webcomponents (mostly PolymerElement/LitElement based).

https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md#register-an-interest-in-specific-key-events